# GET url with nested element inside query string

Tags: sql, url, get, nested, query-string

Using Postman, I am forming a GET request query to my P21 database middleware to retrieve items with a specific value in a UserDefinedField.

I am able to query things on the top level of the item data, such as ItemID and ItemDesc like so:

http://[server]:[port]/api/inventory/parts?$query=ItemDesc eq 'CONTROL VALVE'

However, the values I would like to use in my query string are nested inside the UserDefinedFeilds element. I am specifically looking for items with:

http://[server]:[port]/api/inventory/parts?$query=UserDefinedFeilds/OnEbay eq 'Y'

But this is not the correct way to form this query string. Can anyone please explain how to specify a nested element inside a query string like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, using P21 API, it is unnecessary to specify the parent field 'UserDefinedFields'. The actual ID of the column I was looking for was actually 'on_ebay', so I was able to query this user defined field simply:

http://[server]:[port]/api/inventory/parts?$query=on_ebay eq 'Y'